# Angular JS cancel a debounce function after one itration

Tags: angularjs

I saw in a tutorial a debounce function made for angular js. It works well (but I do not understand the code very well).

The questions are:

Can you explain how this debounce works?

**How can I reset the debounce function after it has worked one time?**

```
function debounce(callback, interval) {
                var timeout = null;
                return function() {
                    $timeout.cancel(timeout);
                    timeout = $timeout(callback, interval);
                };
            };

            inputNgEl.bind('keydown keypress', debounce(function () {
                el.toggleClass('has-error', formCtrl[inputName].$invalid);
                el.toggleClass('has-success', formCtrl[inputName].$valid);
            }, 1000));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can you explain how this debounce works?*

The `debounce(callback, 1000)` returns a new function. So this `inputNgEl.bind('keydown keypress',debounce(callback, 1000))` attaches `function` returned from `debounce` as event handler `inputNgEl`.

When events happen the attached event handler function is called possibly many times in row which results in:

```
time (in 100ms):   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18    
keepresses     :      ↓        ↓                                      ↓
time to fire   :     10  9  8 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  ✦       10  9
callback 
(in 100ms)
```

So when the event handler (returned from `debounce`) is called `timeout` variable is `null`. Calling `$timeout.cancel(null)` does nothing. Next we **schedule** the `callback` function to be executed after `1000 ms` using `$timeout` service call. The call returns a `promise` that will be resolved after the given timeout (`1000ms`) elapses.

Now on second call to event handler the `timeout` variable has a `promise` so we cancel it - the `callback` function wont be called. Next we immediately **schedule** `callback` function again to be executed after `1000 ms` and store a **new** `promise` inside `timeout` variable.

*How can I reset the debounce function after it has worked one time?*

I'm not sure what you mean by **reseting** the function? Immediately after `callback` is called the `debounce` function state and behaviour is almost identical to initial state - except for `timeout` variable.

If you would like to remove the debounce effect after the the `callback` is called for the first time you could do something like:

```
function debounce(callback, interval) {
    var timeout = null;
    var inner = function() {
        $timeout.cancel(timeout);

        if(inner.interval){
            timeout = $timeout(function(){
                callback();
                inner.interval = null;
            }, interval);
        } else {
           callback();
        }
    };
    inner.interval = interval;
    return inner;
};
```

Which basically after first timeout elapses will switch to calling `callback` immediately.